# Design issue regarding multiple TextEditingControllers and possibility to reuse a TextFormField-widget

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I have an app where I have a list of objects. All object are of the same type, but with different data. When I press one of these objects, a dialog open up and give me the possibility to edit several data fields. The table below is an example of one of two tables of data that this object contains. #? Is optional values 1-5 for category a-d. C is a button that is suppose to copy the above values. For instance pressing C in category b copies values 1-5 from category a to 1-5 in category b.
X is a button that resets values 1-5 for each category to the original values.

```
      |#1   |#2   |#3   |#4   |#5   |Reset
 a    |value|value|value|value|value| X
 b C  |value|value|value|value|value| X
 c C  |value|value|value|value|value| X
 d C  |value|value|value|value|value| X
```

In order to access these values and manipulate the TextFormField, I need to use TextEditingController. The only solution I've found so far is to make a map of TestEditingController like this:

```
Map<int, TextEditingController> _controllers;
_controllers.putIfAbsent(0, () => TextEditingController(text: _object.getInitialValue(0)));
_controllers.putIfAbsent(1, () => TextEditingController(text: _object.getInitialValue(1)));
...
_controllers.putIfAbsent(19, () => TextEditingController(text: _object.getInitialValue(19)));
```

And this is for one of the tables. I have two, so there is a lot of _controllers to .putIfAbsent.
I could do this in i for-loop, but still there will be many TextEditingControllers that are created.

Is that an issue or is there a way to do this more smoothly? Do I need to create a TextEdtingController for each TextFormField in the widget?

Each of these TextFormField looks like this:

```
Expanded(
    flex: _COLUMN_2,
    child: TextFormField(
        onChanged: (text) {
            if ( (text.length==0) || (text.compareTo('.')==0) ) text = '0';
            _object.setInitialValue(1, text);
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: _controllers[1],
        inputFormatters: [decimalValidator],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Initial value',
        ),
    )
),
```

That also means a lot of hard coded lines to create all these fields. Is there a more smooth approach to this as well? The code contains nearly 1400 lines now and is quite a nightmare to navigate in. Could this be but in a general prupose widget with parameters and called upon several times? Or a widget that creates each category? A widget that returns this:

```
a    |value|value|value|value|value| X
```

I have not tried the above approach yet. This is because I can not see how to access all the data fields when C is pressed for copy. Is it possible to have a method in the general purpose widget that exposes these values?

Any tips would be much appriciated!

Comment: Are all controllers the same? And the keyboard types?

Comment: All controllers and keyboard types are identical. Each controller has unique (.text) data. I'm currently trying to create a 'general purpuse' TextFieldWidget that can be used. If I succeed, I'll answer my own post...

Comment: Excellent was what I was going to propose in my answer. Even better that you came to that conclusion yourself, keep it up.